# Problems in notations in a paper on Bayesian space-time models

Tags: terminology, hierarchical-bayesian, notation, spatio-temporal

Suppose I have been given some process $Y$. Let $Y(s,t)$ denote the value of process at location $s$ and time $t$. For my experiment, I consider a model described as - $$Y(s,t) =  \mu(s) + M(t;\beta(s)) + X(s,t) + \gamma(s,t)  $$

Here, $\mu(s)$ represents site specific mean $M(t;\beta(s))$ is a large scale temporal model with site specific parameters $\beta(s)$. $X(s,t)$ is a short scale dynamical process. $\gamma(s,t)$ models noise.

I have following questions -

Firstly, $\mu(s)$ is the site specific mean of what? What are the quantities that we are averaging over this space $s$ ?

Secondly, I can't understand what does $ \beta$ and $X$ exactly denote?

All this is given in a paper which I am currently studying - Hierarchical Bayesian space-time models. Here is the link to that paper - http://www.stat.missouri.edu/~wikle/WikleBerlinerCressie1998.pdf

Comment: These are *function* notations. The mean at a site is a function of some characteristics of the site (or just a lookup table, I suppose -- site A is -5, site B is 2, site C is 5/4). M is a function of time and of coefficients which vary by site. X(s,t) is a function of site and time. Gamma is a function of s and time.

Comment: @ user777 - It's clear that $X$ is a function of $s$ and $t$ but what kind of function? What does it represent in the model? In the paper it is given that it represents short time scale dynamical processes? What exactly does the latter term mean in the context of paper?